# How to use a fragment as part of update changeset attributes?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to update an existing model with new attributes and a database call interacting with the existing column. Something like `UPDATE companies SET a = 1, b = jsonb_set(b, '{key}', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), true)` in SQL.

How would I achieve this using Ecto and fragments?

This is my attempt, but it fails since `fragment` is a macro:

```
enhanced =
  %{ attrs | b: fragment(
    "jsonb_set(b, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), true)",
    "{#{Atom.to_string(key)}}"
  )}
result =
  company
  |> Company.changeset(enhanced)
  |> Repo.update()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the fragment macro via `Ecto.Query.update` is the way to go. To do that, we will need to make the update *part of* the query expression.

```
{count, results} =
  Company
  |> where([c], <some_condition>)
  |> select([e], e) ## Optional: this will return our changes
  |> update(set: [
        string_field: "value",
        map_field: fragment(~S<jsonb_set("map_field"::jsonb, '{key_name_here}', 'value_here')>)
      ]
  |> Repo.update_all([])
```

The `~S<…>` is used to avoid escaping the quotation marks `"` in our fragment.

Add variables to your fragment by replacing them in your string with a `?` and adding them as a pinned `^` param.

```
fragment(~S<jsonb_set("map_field"::jsonb, '{?}', 'value_here')>, ^key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to add the fragment to the original query, but calling `jsonb_set` can be achieved kind-of atomatically using a transaction.

```
Repo.transaction(fn ->
  updated = case update_company(company, attrs) do
    {:ok, company} -> company
    {:error, changeset} -> Repo.rollback(changeset)
  end

  from(c in Company,
      update: [set: [b: fragment(
        "jsonb_set(b, ?, to_jsonb(now()), true)",
        ^key
      )]],
      where: c.id == ^company.id)
    |> Repo.update_all([])

  updated
end)
```